# MongoDB truncating LocalDateTime nanosecs when MongoTemplate persists the data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Spring Boot 2 project using MongoDB as database.

When I Instantiate an object containing a date as LocalDateTime by calling LocalDateTime.now(); I receive a datetime containing nanoseconds with more than 4 numerical places.

When I persist this data in mongoDB using mongotemplate.save, the value is saved containing 3 places for nanoseconds only (the rest is filled with zero). So, how can I accomplish the same precision when storing to DB? Or another option: how would I limit the precision when creating a LocalDateTime instance in java?

```java
@Document("Entity")
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(name = "created")
    private LocalDateTime created;

    public HistoryEntity(){
        // This gives me 2020-01-30T13:25:09.817182
        this.created = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public class DAO {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    public void save(Entity e) {
        // When value is persisted, I get 2020-01-30T13:25:09.817 if I look into mongoDB instance or if I retrieve the same entity from DB in Java
        Entity saved = mongoTemplate.save(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using java 11, so, that's why my LocalDateTime has a nanoseconds precision. But I haven't found anywhere how to increase mongoDB time precision.

Comment: I also found out how to limit LocalDateTime to milliseconds by assigning a lower precision clock to it, but I just think that isn't the best idea:
Clock millisecondClock = Clock.tick(Clock.systemDefaultZone(), Duration.ofNanos(1000000));
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.now(millisecondClock);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found out the answer and probably there isn't much I can do other than truncate my LocalDateTime from java side (As I explained in my last comment and depicted below)

```
Clock millisecondClock = Clock.tick(Clock.systemDefaultZone(), Duration.ofNanos(1000000)); 
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.now(millisecondClock);
```

I was reading this Baeldung's article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-zoneddatetime when I faced the following statement (which answered my question):

> ... we're removing the nanoseconds information since the MongoDB Date type has a precision of milliseconds:

So that's it. Even if I want to work with a higher precision, seems that MongoDB can't handle it (at least for now)

Answer (score 0):

If the `LocalDateTime` fields are only used for audit purposes (i.e. you don't need to query entities having a date/time field before/after a certain point in time)
you can store date/time as a `String`, and deserialize the field back to your date/time object when retrieving the entity.

You can achieve this by registering custom converters in your mongo configuration. The following example is for `Instant` because I'm using `Instant` for audit fields rather than `LocalDateTime`, but you can easily adapt it for your need.

```
@Configuration
public class MongoCustomConfig {

  @Bean
  MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
    return new MongoCustomConversions(
        List.of(instantStringConverter()));
  }

  @Bean
  InstantStringConverter instantStringConverter() {
    return new InstantStringConverter();
  }

  private static class InstantStringConverter implements Converter<Instant, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(Instant source) {
      return source.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: by the way I realized that you could still use the date/time stored in mongo as text for your queries, you'd just need to convert them with some function like `$dateFromString`, it's up to you to decide if it's worth it or not.